# Edited: Why was learning Fullstack React confusing?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

- Update: When I first started with this question I was basically struggling to understand what I needed to do in order to make my frontend interact with the backend. 
  To answer my own question in case new guys come in:

  1. If you use ejs, you are using server side rendering, meanwhile if you work your frontend separated your backend, you'll mostly be working with APIs.
  2. First learn Node. Than work your way through on how APIs work. After feeling comfortable, start learning React.
  3. Yes its normal. Just start building a project or else you'll stay in that tutorial hell.

---

So I have basic knowledge about React, intermediate level on javascript... and now I have taken a node with mongodb course. So I know that, i'll be feeding my tutorial hell if I do not put all those together and start building something from scratch. But till now, I have only rendered the EJS files and know how to setup everything from the ejs view point. 
So now I feel quite lost as if someone gave me a puzzle with missing pieces. 
I know some of you guys have taken this road so I have a couple of questions, even though some sound quite stupid:

1. How can node code be affected introducing reactJs, because I am currently using res.render('ejsViewFile')?
2. When you guys first learned this approach for using the MERN Stack, how did you learn to connect both of them? I find a lot of tutorials... but they confuse me even more.
3. Is this normal... me feeling like I have learned absolutely NOTHING?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's great to see such type of questions.
I have also developed web application in which I have to just use the node JS and react with multiple microservices.

so I am also going through from such tutorials on udemy and other tutorials that are available on the website.
I found out that you can use react JS as a front UI and you can use node JS for backend if you don't want to use spring boot for your microservices it is just fine.

So basically I have developed rest API in node JS and using axios and promise I am calling that API from my react applications so I think in that way you can connect both of the applications.
 in most of the applications I have seen that node JS is used for security purposes in the following purposes and then node JS is connected to a microservice it is just kind of adding another layer over your application.
I prefer lead can tell you that you can go through the udemy courses of react JS and it will show you how you can create a rest API on the node JS.

React for UI
Nodejs: api gateway or backend. You wish
Java : microservices, rest apis